# Change Zoom Selection Rectangle Color in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, mschart

How can I change color of selection rectangle in MSChart in VB.NET?

The image is shown below to clear my question a bit:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to use the Cursor X and Cursor Y properties to set the selection color.  Should be something like:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionColor = Color.Lime;
chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SelectionColor = Color.Lime;
```